# How to print on the same line in a loop?

Tags: printing, python-3.x, console-output

I am trying to print results on the same line for a card game, here is the desired output I want:

[image: desired output]

Here is what I get:

[image: actual ouput]

Here is my code:

```
  for List in tableau:
        print
        print ("Row", Row, ":", end="")
        print
        Row += 1
        for x in List:
            print (x, end="")
```

I'm using Python 3, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding the newline generation behaviour of Python's print statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677424/overriding-the-newline-generation-behaviour-of-pythons-print-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `print` as a function in Python 3:

```
for List in tableau:
      print()  # Right here
      print ("Row", Row, ":", end="")

      Row += 1
      for x in List:
          print (x, end="")
```

Look at the difference in the output between Python 2 and Python 3:

**Python 2**:

```
>>> print

>>>
```

**Python 3**:

```
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> print()

>>>
```

A slightly more compact way of doing it would be like this:

```
for index, row in enumerate(tableau, start=1):
    print('Row {index} : {row}'.format(index=index, row=' '.join(row)))
```

Comment: This might just be the one, the obvious way to do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `print`s to be functions.

```
for List in tableau:
    print()
    print ("Row", Row, ":", end="")
    print()
    Row += 1
    for x in List:
        print (x, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for List in tableau:
    print("\n")
    print ("Row", Row, ":", "")

    print("\n")
    Row += 1
    for x in List:
        print (x, end="")
```

That should do the trick. It worked for me.